Aws Glue startup time
I have aws glue job which processing CSV file from s3 and inserting into database. What I observed that there is 20-22 sec time lag between driver added and first job submitted.
Any idea why it is taking time or how we can improve startup time.

You can check a few things like number and type of workers, if the data volume is not much, try reducing the number of dpus as they can take time starting up.

@samhita Thanks for reply. I tried with G2.X from G1.X, it improves overall job time. Also, one observation DPU reduction does not help much and startup time taking around ~12 sec. Seems like aws glue has cold start time more than ~10 sec.

ok so you mean reducing worker helped improving start time  from 22 sec to around ~12 sec?
and yes glue does have some cold start time which you mentioned

Worker type change help. Reduce dsu does not help much.

Few options can be tried to reduce the startup time of Glue jobs
Glue Job Configuration:

Worker Type and Number: Experiment with different worker types and numbers to find the optimal configuration for your specific workload.


[As confirmed in comments changing the worker type has improved the
startup time]


Try reducing the number of dpus as they can take time starting up.


Thanks for providing valuable suggestions
